# How to do custom ordering of a Django queryset?

Tags: python, django

A little background about our specific problem ->

We are trying to build a Q & A site, much like Stackoverflow.
People can come and ask questions and other people reply.

So like SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions) we have a questions page. Now the problem we're having is that we have this model :

```
class Questions(models.Models):   
    user = person
    question = CharField   
    number_of_replies = IntegerField  
    datetime = DateTime
```

The resultant queryset ( or list ) is determined by a combination of various factors like when it was posted, how many people replied to it, etc.

Since there's been confusion related to the question i'll clarify it ->
This is the kind of output I'm looking for :

This is how the final order will be ->

1. Question c posted 10 mins ago, 0 replies
2. Question f posted 1 min ago, 2 replies
3. Question b posted 5 mins ago, 1 reply
   etc.
   so there is no one-dimensional order, the order is a function of various parameters

Comment: What do mean by "order of priority"? Do you want one combined query or one query for each case?

Comment: I would be looking for a combined query sir

Comment: But I'm not really sure what I am looking for, now I feel that maybe lists is a better way to go about this kinda thing

Comment: From the example order you've given, I think what you have is a problem with the **design** of your app rather than the **implementation**. Why would an older question with less replies  be higher on a list (question c before question f) and yet on the same list an older question with less replies is ranked lower (question b is below question f)? Check out the SO Questions page that you've linked to: the ranking of questions by time posted and number of replies is actually on two different lists (Newest and Active).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is by defining a custom manager ->

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance.

You can display the objects in any order you like. You can even return lists and self-defined dictionaries using the custom manager methods.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your required clause represents a queryset.

Questions that are unanswered and posted in the last "X" mins:

```
unanswered_questions = Question.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=(now()-time(min=5))).annotate(answers_count=Count('Answer')).filter(answers_count=0)
```

And similarly.

Seems like you want to display a combination of a few querysets. You can use the `itertools.chain` method for that, to combine and display the result of a few querysets in your template, like:

```
combined_queryset = chain(recent_questions,unanswered_questions,...)
```

Keep in mind however that if there is an overlapping condition on these querysets, some questions can get repeated. You may avoid that by explicitly converting the result of the one queryset in the next ones, or you may convert queryset into list and let the `set.union` type take care of possible duplicates.

Comment: Hey thank you for replying, I get what you're trying to do but this is not hitting the nail ( if you know what i mean ). I have edited the question, check it out